# Proper way to add a user account via bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, users, useradd

I cross posted this question to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319714/proper-way-to-add-a-user-accout-via-bash-script) because my problem seems most acute on Debian/Ubuntu, but it was suggested that I ask here. Whatever method is suggested for solving this problem should work on most distros (e.g., openSuse & Ubuntu). Here's the script code I'm using now:

```
getent group $MYGROUP
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    sudo su -c "groupadd $MYGROUP"
fi
sudo su -c "useradd mynewuser -p mypassword -m -g $PRIMARYGRP -G $MYGROUP"
```

There are several problems with the user account it creates on Ubuntu.

- the terminal prompt isn't set (`echo $PS1` returns nothing)
- the arrow keys and tab key do not work correctly in the terminal
- the password doesn't seem to work (although I'm still unclear exactly what this issue is)
- the /etc/sudoers rights set for this new user are not honored

If instead I manually create the user with `adduser` (instead of useradd) I don't have these problems. But I need a non-Debian-exclusive script or method of adding user accounts via my bash script.

I also had a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79909/how-to-add-a-unix-linux-user-in-a-bash-script) on this topic, but it was different enough that it is not relevant to this problem.

Comment: This question was duplicated on ask ubuntu? http://askubuntu.com/q/319714/250556

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the default shell for a new user on Debian is `/bin/sh` so most of the features you're used to from `bash` aren't there. Try adding `-s /bin/bash` to your `useradd` command.

You can also change the default shell permanently by editing `/etc/default/useradd`.

**Edit:**

The solution to automatically modify the password (as found by MountainX) is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57806/15010)

Comment: thanks I will add that. I also need to solve the [skeleton files issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82928/15010).

Comment: @MountainX Have you made sure that the `.bashrc` file hasn't been copied correctly? I have seen the behavior you describe on Debian before: `.bashrc` is copied correctly but is never used since the default shell is `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`. Just try setting the shell to `/bin/bash` and I bet most of your issues will disappear.

Comment: @MountainX For reference purposes, though, the skeleton directory on Debian is `/etc/skel`

Comment: Solution Summary: for the password problem, this solution works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57806/15010. For the cursor key and prompt problems, adding `-s /bin/bash` to my existing useradd command works. The .bashrc files is indeed already present. I wish I could select both the answers by @UlrichSchwarz and @Joseph.

Comment: @MountainX Answer updated to add your solution to the password issue.

Answer (score 3):

The cursor key and prompt problems sound like the skeleton files are not copied properly. Does the new user's home directory have a `.bashrc`?

As to the password, `man useradd` on Slack tells me

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

so you're probably not supposed to put the plaintext password there. I can't find a convenient way to call crypt manually right now, though, so maybe you'll need an extra call to `sudo passwd $mynewuser`.

Comment: thank you! Do you have any idea where the SKEL files are that are used by default by Ubuntu with the adduser script (as opposed to useradd)?

Comment: @MountainX: I'm not a Debian/Ubuntu person, try `/etc/skel` or `/etc/skel.d` maybe?

Comment: what do you think of this answer? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57806/15010 Should I try that?

Comment: Can't hurt to try. :)

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if `mkpasswd(1)` would help instead of `crypt`. It is Debian/Ubuntu-specific, though

Comment: Solution Summary: for the password problem, this solution works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57806/15010. For the cursor key and prompt problems, adding `-s /bin/bash` to my existing useradd command works. The .bashrc files is indeed already present. I wish I could select both the answers by @UlrichSchwarz and @Joseph.