# usermod to change user password is not working

Tags: users, password, useradd, passwd

I have created user using below command

```
useradd myuser
```

Then, I tried to do change password with following command

```
usermod --password mypwd myuser
```

(I know plain password is not a good way, but for time being I am doing this)

I have tried to login `myuser` with `mypwd`. But, it's not allowing to login (incorrect password).

I could use `passwd myuser` (working fine). There are some constraints, so I am doing with `usermod`.

Is anything I am missing in `usermod` ? or Is there any alternatives to do change password other than `passwd username`?

Comment: See [How can I assign an initial/default password to a user in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57796/how-can-i-assign-an-initial-default-password-to-a-user-in-linux)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameter given to [`usermod --password`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html) is expected to be the encrypted password, as returned by the [`crypt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function. If you look in `/etc/shadow` (assuming you're using local password storage) you'll see the string you specified stored as-is in `myuser`'s entry...

If you really want to use `usermod` for this, you can generate the appropriate value using `openssl passwd`:

```
usermod --password $(openssl passwd mypwd) myuser
```

or better still

```
usermod --password $(openssl passwd -1 mypwd) myuser
```

Comment: Just to reinforce that one should use `-1`, otherwise `openssl` will default to `-crypt` and truncate the password at 8 chars with a "Warning: truncating password to 8 characters" message.